# Spring security - Access denied to authorised user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to validate and authenticate my users. Authentication works perfectly fine but when a user is redirected to a page on login that requires specific access, it goes to the Access Denied page (The user has the required access)

Here's my Spring security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="emailId"
            password-parameter="pwd" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>
```

Here's the last part of the console logs:

```
2016-05-31 12:37:39 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:348 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@2586e756: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@4361438: Username: test@test.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted **Authorities: ADMIN**,USER-EX; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EF69C8E091A4AFEA8B043CC29AF29AE0; Granted Authorities: ADMIN, USER-EX
2016-05-31 12:37:39 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6eb2a0ec, returned: -1
2016-05-31 12:37:39 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:186 - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

As you can see, the log says the user is authenticated and has "ADMIN" access and should be able to view the /welcome page but that isn't happening.

Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Spring version - 4.2.6
Spring Security - 4.1.0
Java - 1.8

Comment: <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />

Comment: And you are using spring 4 so use java config https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTDNgD1Iz6c

Comment: @LynAs corrected my typo. But the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a single "/" that was playing truant.

**Changed** `<intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />` **to** `<intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />`

I have seen tutorials where the pattern is "/abc/**" Can anyone tell me the difference between single * and double? Thanks

Comment: To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned authorization for "/welcome"

Ex:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Comment: I have added this (edited the typo actually) but the issue persists.